# Как подключить ssl сертификат на сервер на socket.io, node.js, redis, express.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, socket.io, redis

Сделал socket.io сервер по туториалу. Появилась проблема с подключением к серверу через https запрос. Объясните, пожалуйста, как подключить ssl сертификаты конкретно в данном случае.

```js
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("new client connected");

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('notification');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = require('express')();
var redis = require('redis');
var server = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
},app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8890);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("new client connected");

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('notification');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });

});
```